# Randomly shuffle query results where values are the same

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Performing an `order_by` operation on an SQLAlchemy query, where the objects being sorted have the same value, always returns them in the order that they are in the database.

Is there a function to additionally shuffle those results that are the same?

---

*Practical example*:

```
ITEM         PRICE

hamburger    20
burrito      10
sandwich     10
quesadilla   15
```

Running `db.session.query(FoodItem).order_by(FoodItem.price).all()` would return them in the following order:

1. Hamburger
2. Quesadilla
3. **Burrito**
4. **Sandwich**

`burrito` would always precede `sandwich` as it is earlier in the database, no matter how many times you ran the function.

I've tried to randomly sort the results before ordering, as so:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import func

db.session.query(FoodItem).order_by(func.random()).order_by(FoodItem.price).all()
```

However, this doesn't have the desired effect - the final order is still retained according to the database. Is there a way - `sqlalchemy` or a Python lambda expression/function - to achieve the desired result of *sorted items, with items having equal values shuffled*?

Comment: "always returns them in the order that they are in the database" is not exactly true, or guaranteed. For example a parallel query plan could mix the order up. Put another way: there is no order in the database in SQL. The only way to guarantee order is to use ORDER BY. Of course an implementation can most of the time read the rows like they happen to be on disk, but the disk order can also change, and different plans read differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the correct `order_by()` call order when passing in multiple criteria; the criteria are ordered from most-significant to least, the first `order_by` option applies to all rows, the second only to rows where the first option is equal.

So, if only items with the same price need to be randomised, put the random order last:

```
db.session.query(FoodItem).order_by(FoodItem.price).order_by(func.random())
```

Note that `Query.order_by()` takes multiple criteria, you don't *have* to use multiple calls:

```
db.session.query(FoodItem).order_by(FoodItem.price, func.random())
```

So rows are first sorted by price, then if two rows have the same price, the next criteria is used and so are randomised *within the same price group only*.

For future reference: *print* your query object (without the `.all()`) to get an idea what SQL is being generated; e.g. using my best guess as to what your model might look like, your query produces:

```sql
SELECT food_item.id AS food_item_id, food_item.name AS food_item_name, food_item.price AS food_item_price
FROM food_item ORDER BY random(), food_item.price
```

and by swapping the criteria you get:

```sql
SELECT food_item.id AS food_item_id, food_item.name AS food_item_name, food_item.price AS food_item_price
FROM food_item ORDER BY food_item.price, random()
```

Side note: `random()` is specific to PostgreSQL and SQLite, if you need to support other databases you'll need to adjust the expression.